# How to fix the unsuccessfully loaded data files written outside the sequence folder of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone ever encountered data files written outside the `sequence` folder in Version 0.13.3 of Apache IoTDB? There is no problem with normal operation, but after restarting, this part of the data will not be successfully loaded due to path problems. Anyone know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, try to copy these data files written outside the `sequence` folder and reload them using the `load` command in Apache IoTDB.